Is it possible to write Mint panel applet that displays an editable text entry?
I would like to create a text entry that would evaluate some text upon the ENTER key-press. Is it somehow possible? So far I tried this by setting the IconApplet actor property at launch to new St.Entry instance:
var REPLApplet = class REPLApplet extends Applet.IconApplet {
    _init(orientation, panel_height, instance_id) {
        super._init(orientation, panel_height, instance_id);
        this._entry_field = new St.Entry({"text": "Hello?"})
        
        this.actor = this._entry_field
}

It worked fine, I've got the entry displayed:

But it doesn't capture the key events (it's not editable even though the cursor is there - the key events are dispatched to a window that has the focus).
I tried searching for examples, but none of the panel applets appear to do a similar thing.
